# Error google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file with Robolectric 2 and Google Play Services (maps V2)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2, robolectric

I have an Android application with Google Maps V2 configured with maven in Eclipse. So I have a "mavenised" Google Play Services lib in the worspace, and the app pom has two maven dependencies to google-play-services jar and apklib.

I implemented a dummy test which only checks if a map fragment is not null:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MapsTest {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private ElementMapActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = new ElementMapActivity();
        activity.onCreate(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void mapExists() {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.elementMap)).getMap();
        Assert.assertNotNull(map);
    }   
}
```

Note: a similar code is used in the real application activity to show the map, and it runs OK.

I don't implement any custom testrunners.

I run the test with maven: mvn test.

With Robolectric 1.2 the test builds and executes, but the assertNotNull fails, as the map instance is null. The fragment is not correctly recovered.

With Robolectric 2.1.1 the test builds but fails to execute. I get an exception for each test in the project (not only for the one that tests the maps):

```
WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc
java.lang.RuntimeException: .\..\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.validate(AndroidManifest.java:108)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getResourcePath(AndroidManifest.java:274)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:280)
    at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:282)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:576)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:568)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:89)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:387)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:227)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

It seems that Robolectric tries to use the google-play-services library manifest instead of the main application manifest, which is in the default location: the app root folder. The library manifest is in it's own root folder as well.

Am I missing some configuration for the tests? Should I use a custom testrunner? Or is it that Google Maps V2 are not supported with Robolectric 2?

Edit: I can do without the maps tests. The problem is that with Robolectric 2 all the other tests get this error too, just by having the google-play-library dependency, so I can not use Robolectric 2 by now. I would like to know if this is a known bug in order to decide to go back to Robolectric 1 or not. I checked Robolectric bug reports and didn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered the same problem with ActionBarSherlock when running my Robolectric tests under my Maven build plan.

The problem was not evident when I was completing builds on a Windows machine and only became apparent after I switched my laptop for a OSX power device.

I found that the problem was that the library name "google-play-services_lib" doesn't (exactly) match that of the folder name in the directory structure. In my case, my Eclipse project was called "ActionBarSherlock-4.3.1" whereas the folder itself was called "actionbarsherlock" under the file system.

I recommend that you synchronise the two names (Eclipse project and file system) and re-run your tests. Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked the folder and project name, and they match, no luck. Anyway thanks for your help, I was quite stuck and your answer gave me some ideas, like moving the library project to a different folder, or renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

Testing Android Apps, with Robolectric 2.1.1, that use google-play-services_lib (Google Maps) produces AndroidManifest.xml not found RuntimeException.

**The short answer is here in bold. The long answer is below it.**

**Look in your project for a file named project.properties**

**Create a new file called test-project.properties**

**Override any or all of the android.library.reference.$**

**For example in my project.properties it had this library reference:**

```
**android.library.reference.1=../../../ADK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib**
```

**I overrode it in the test-project.properties file**

**android.library.reference.1=res**

**Put the AndroidManifest.xml from the google-play-services_lib into the res(or any folder in the project) folder of the project you are testing**

The long answer:

I was having the same issue and was thinking the problem was the same as described above "google-play-services library manifest instead of the main application manifest"  So I removed all my references to the google-place-services_lib and still received the error.  I downloaded the 2.1.1 Robolectric code from github and started debugging through it. I found that org.robolectric.AndroidManifest class has a method called getLibraryManifests which calls createLibraryManifests and that calls findLibraries. One of the things it does is loads the project.properties file in your project.  In my case my project.properties file at this content:
   android.library.reference.1=../../../ADK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

This was created when I used the Android Tools for the google play services install per Google's documentation.   If you comment out that line from project.properties file then the error goes away.  A better solution is to leave it and then create your own file called test-project.properties and put in the correct directory for android.library.reference.1 and the AndroidManifest will override the original value.

Here is the relevant code from AndroidManifest.java

```
protected List<FsFile> findLibraries() {
FsFile baseDir = getBaseDir();
List<FsFile> libraryBaseDirs = new ArrayList<FsFile>();

Properties properties = getProperties(baseDir.join("project.properties"));
// get the project.properties overrides and apply them (if any)
Properties overrideProperties = getProperties(baseDir.join("test-project.properties"));
if (overrideProperties!=null) properties.putAll(overrideProperties);
if (properties != null) {
int libRef = 1;
String lib;
while ((lib = properties.getProperty("android.library.reference." + libRef)) != null) {
FsFile libraryBaseDir = baseDir.join(lib);
libraryBaseDirs.add(libraryBaseDir);
libRef++;
}
}
return libraryBaseDirs;
}
```